# Cvs2svn conversion failure , Status =1

Tags: svn, cvs, cvs2svn

I am using cvs2svn to convert a bunch of cvs files from my Repository over to svn. Now for the most part its just very slow but its going there. My main problem are a few files showing up with a error output like this.

ERROR: the command 'cvs -q -R -f -d C:\CVSRepo co -r1.2 -p HEAD/xxx/xx/Afile.java' failed with exit status =1

and the following output:

cvs checkout: cannot find module 'HEAD/xxx/xx/afile' -ignored

Now I can see the file showing up just fine, but i cant get past that subversion. its always on a the same number on step 16. I don't know what to do and any advice or suggestions would be appreciated and welcomed :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen this problem before.  I have two guesses and two suggestions:

Guess 1: The fact that you have a directory named "HEAD" is confusing CVS, for which "HEAD" means the main branch.  As a test, try renaming that directory and then converting.

Guess 2: You are using CVS modules, and they are confusing CVS when it tries to extract the file content from the repository.  As a test, try removing the "modules" file and then converting.

Suggestion 1: Make sure you are using the latest version of cvs2svn and try using --use-internal-co (which bypasses CVS altogether).

Suggestion 2: Take your question over to the cvs2svn users mailing list, where it is easier to hold a conversation.

Comment: Thank you that helped . I was using the switch --use-cvs but the internal co was not only faster but successful.